# Missing menu items for files

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am missing a number of menu items when I click the three dots next to a file name.

Below is an example of the options I have for a given file and the options a colleague in my company has.

It doesn't matter if I created the file or someone else has. I have this problem for all the files I've tested so far.

[image: This is what I see]

[image: This is what my colleague sees]

Answer (score 0):

This could occurs due to the item level permission in the document library. So verify the item level permissions for two items where it shows full menu and does not show up full menu.

Refer to the below MSDN article how item level permission is configured :

[Customize permissions for a SharePoint list or library](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-permissions-for-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782?ocmsassetid=ha102833689&correlationid=a66eafdd-2629-419d-976f-2be0d25cb81f&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)

Answer (score 0):

This issue should be about your permissions on the library. You can ask your colleague(your account should be not able to do that) to go to the **library settings** and click "**Permissions for this library**", then check your account permissions and your colleague's account permissions via "**Check Permissions**", compare the differences between them. To have the same options as your colleague, you need to have the same permissions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is a browser issue in my case: Chrome shows me a limited set of options whereas Edge shows me the full list. I am not quite clear why that's the case but for now that's a workaround I can live with.